# optional initialisation properties for new Javascript object

Tags: javascript, oop, object, arguments, default

Is this the correct way to make a javascript class with default properties (even though some here are null), yet also having the **option** to add a creation argument that can contain specific values for some properties listed in object format/json?

Also should i put any of this into Person's prototype to save memory if I am creating many Person objects?

this is working for me but I wonder if it is a good way to do this ?

```
// PERSON Class -----------------------------------------------
 QM.Person=function(data)
 {
    /* Closure for this */
    var my = this;

    this.PersonID=null;
    this.Name_Last="";
    this.Name_First="";
    this.Date_Birth=null;
    this.Biography="";

    this.loadData=function(obj) {
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (my.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                my[i] = obj[i];
            }
        }
    }

    this.loadData(data);
}
```

example of creating using this class:

```
jondoe = new Person();

bob = new Person({Name_First:"Bob",Name_Last:"Bar"});

jondoe.Name_First   /*  ""     */
bob.Name_First     /*   "Bob"  */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid repeating yourself you could build a list of keys you expect and also the default values to insert if they aren't specified:

```
MyType = function(data){
    var keys = this.keys,
        data = data || {},
        key

    for (key in keys) {
        if (keys.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                this[key] = data[key];
            } else {
                this[key] = keys[key];
            }
        }
    }      
};

MyType.prototype.keys = {
    personId: null,
    firstName: 'A default first name',
    lastName: ''
};

var o1 = new MyType();
var o2 = new MyType({
    personId: 1,
    firstName: 'Override'
});
console.log(o1, o2);
```

Comment: I have gone with the above answer, though rewritten the `for` `in` statement as :`/* Evaluate initialisation data */
    for(var key in this.defaults) 
    {
            this[key] = (data !== undefined && data[key] !== undefined) ? data[key] : this.defaults[key];
    }`

Comment: that should have been: `for(var key in keys) { this[key] = (data !== undefined && data[key] !== undefined) ? data[key] : keys[key]; }` where `keys = this.keys`

Comment: That's functionally no different, arguably worse because you should have the hasOwnProperty check there.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it that way.  I would do

```
QM.Person=function(data)
{
    data = data || {};

    this.PersonID= data.PersonId || null; 
    this.Name_Last= data.Name_Last || ""; 
    ...
}
```

You will note I am assuming you care about the explicit type, i.e. when you assign `null`, you want `null`, and not `undefined`. Same thing for `""`.

I think this is just simpler than creating a function and executing it to clean up your data

Finally, all methods your want to add to the function should be on the prototype.  Properties should **NOT** be on the prototype, unless you want all instances to share the same properties.  Since you don't have any methods other than your data-cleaner, nothing you have shown should go on the prototype.

Comment: that will work, but is there a way to avoid typing the ".PersonID",".Name_Last", .. etc more than once ?? The reason I ask is because I have a mysql table, PHP class, Json keys, and this Person class all using the same property name but I would like to limit the number of times I need to type it. otherwise, i like your suggestion